# Modifying an external model

Tags: qt, qabstractitemmodel

I have a tree (scene graph) that I want to display through `QTreeView`. `SceneGraphModel` is a sub-class of `QAbstractItemModel` and implements all methods necessary to display the tree and hands out `QModelIndexS` with a pointer to the `Node` they reference.

This worked pretty well until I tried to manipulate the `SceneGraph` directly. This caused a segfault because the treeview tried to use the now invalid `Node` Pointers in the `QModelIndex`.

Do I have to do all manipulation of the `SceneGraph` through the `SceneGraphModel`? Is there a way around this?

Comment: Is the model accessed _during_ `SceneGraph` update or _after_ `SceneGraph` update ?